# How to send request from interceptor again in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have `Vue` application.

I'm using custom interceptor, After I got the response (in next callback), how do I send the request again?

for example:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {

 next(response => {

  doSomethingLong().then(() => {
   // send again the same request:  Vue.http.<what to write here?>(request )
  });
 });

});
```

Yeah, I know I can investigate the request object, `request.url`, `request.body` and so on.. but I looking for much intelligent solution from the vue-resource box.

Comment: where do you want to send again your request object?